# Architecture for simple timer app

Tags: java, android, timer

I am currently working on a very simple countdown timer app. I need some advice on the correct architecture for a timer which can both fire when the app is closed but also show the progress when the app is open.

What I had until now is a simple `Handler` which executes a `Runnable` every 100 ms to update the progress bar and call the handler again like this

```
// ...
// start the timer

tickHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
// ...

private Handler tickHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(tick()){
            tickHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }
};
```

Now I wanted to be able to have the `Timer` running even when the app is closed. I first thought about a `Service` but then discovered the `AlarmManager` class which seams to do the job and is much easier to use. However I not only want to be able to post a notification to the notification center but also want the app opened up again and showing that the timer has finished.

Can this be done with the `AlarmManager` or do I need to implement a `Service`? How would the architecture for this application look like in terms of where is the control passed from the `Activity` to the `Service` and more importantly back again?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Either approach will work fine (thought, if you use the AlarmManager, you'll still need to keep track of the time for your visual representation of the timer when your Activity is visible). Just select the approach that you believe is the easiest for you to understand and implement. And read up on the Activity lifecycle. You'll make some mistakes initially in understanding the Activity lifecycle (but that will be perfectly normal, that life cycle is initially not intuitive at all, and working through it with an example like yours is the best way to learn).

Comment: Yes I think I will use the AlarmManager together with my already working Handler to track the time when the app is open. I will look into the Activity lifecycle in more detail to get it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the AlarmManager does exactly what you want:

Taken from [Android AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.

So you can register the Intent, which you want to start after the Timer has finished and show the user that the Timer has stopped. Therefore, the AlarmManager should do the trick!

Btw: Using a Service may also work but brings other implications. For example, your app would have to be started during boot phase, which would disable it to be installed on external storage. See [Android Install Locations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)

Comment: So then I will try to use the AlarmManager. Thanks and I will keep the  Service implications in mind!